# Class can.Logger

Tags: python, can-bus

I have an issue where my CAN logger isn’t logging any data that is transmitted. I can’t paste the code here now, but I do have a couple of messages transmitted at a 500 ms periodicity for about 500 seconds. As soon as that part of the code is over, I have the following:

```
logger =can.Logger(path.filename)
logger.stop()
```

After the execution, I do see an ascii file generated at the path mentioned above but no data from the messages transmitted.

I used PCAN viewer application to verify that the messages were transmitted and I did see it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but the answer may be useful for someone: What is missing here is `can.Listener` defined, in order for the logger to collect data.